# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: ee2, error, login, sessions

I am getting this error.I am not able to find out what is causing this error.

```
//A PHP Error was encountered
//
//Severity: 4096
//
//Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
//
//Filename: libraries/Template.php
//
//Line Number: 2929
```

I have made a service page that authinticates the user(login and signup).

I know the code is long and I should have cropped the question,but I am stuck at this since long time now and cant find where the error exist.Can any body help.

Code:

```
<?php

class autologin_signup {
    /**********SIGNUP FUNCTION************/
    public function signup($member_data_signup){

        $EE_signup = & get_instance(); //Access super Object using this instance within function
        //global $FNS, $IN, $LOC, $TMPL, $DB, $SESS, $PREFS; //deprecated
        $this->group_id     = $member_data_signup['group_id'];
        $this->email      = $member_data_signup['email'];
        $this->screen_name    = str_replace(" ","-",strtolower($member_data_signup['name']));
        $this->password     = $member_data_signup['password'];

        //error_log("Tempcode: ".$this->tempCode."-------Email--------".$this->email."-------Location-------".$this->location."-----Screen Name------ ".$this->screen_name);
        $member_id = $EE_signup->session->userdata['member_id'];

        //error_log("Member_id:".$member_id ."-------".print_r($member_data_signup, 1));

        if(!$member_id){
            $username = $this->email;
            $sql= "SELECT exp_members.password, exp_members.unique_id, exp_members.member_id, exp_members.group_id FROM exp_members WHERE email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'";
            $query = $EE_signup->db->query($sql);


            //  creating a new member starts
            if ($query->num_rows == 0){
                $data['username']         = $this->email;
                $data['password']         = $EE_signup->functions->hash(stripslashes($this->password));
                $data['ip_address']       = $EE_signup->input->ip_address();
                $data['unique_id']        = $EE_signup->functions->random('encrypt');
                $data['join_date']        = $EE_signup->localize->now;
                $data['email']            = $this->email;
                //many more!!!
                $query2 = $EE_signup->db->query("SELECT exp_members.screen_name, exp_members.username, exp_members.group_id FROM exp_members WHERE  screen_name like '%".$screen_name."%'");

                //making a unique screen name code

                if ($query2->num_rows != 0){

                    $countstr = $query2->num_rows;
                    $data['screen_name'] = $screen_name . $countstr;
                }else{
                    $data['screen_name'] = $screen_name;
                }

                $EE_signup->db->query($EE_signup->db->insert_string('exp_members', $data));

                $member_id = $EE_signup->db->insert_id();

                $member_data['member_id']     =   $member_id;
                $member_data['m_field_id_1']  = $this->full_name;
                $member_data['m_field_id_2']  = 0;            //isAccountLinked
                $member_data['m_field_id_8']  = $this->phone_number;
                $member_data['m_field_id_9']  = $member_data_signup['gender'];
                $member_data['m_field_id_13']  = $member_data_signup['newsletter_signed_up'];

                $sql5 = "SELECT exp_members.member_id FROM exp_members WHERE exp_members.email='" . $this->email . "'";
                $query5 = $EE_signup->db->query($sql5);

                $EE_signup->db->query($EE_signup->db->insert_string('exp_member_data', $member_data));
                $member_id = $EE_signup->db->insert_id();

                //Member Creation Complete

            } else { // already  user...
                //echo 'already user';
                echo '-3';

                //exit(0);
            }
            return true;

            /** ----------------------------------------
            /**  Update existing session variables
            /** ----------------------------------------*/
            $EE_signup->session->userdata['screen_name']  = $data['screen_name'];
            $EE_signup->session->userdata['username']     = $data['username'];
            $EE_signup->session->userdata['member_id']    = $data['member_id'];
            $EE_signup->session->userdata['group_id']     = $data['group_id'];

            /** ----------------------------------------
            /**  Update stats
            /** ----------------------------------------*/

            $data = array(
                'member_id'   => $EE_signup->session->userdata['member_id'],
                'name'      => ($EE_signup->session->userdata['screen_name'] == '') ? $EE_signup->session->userdata['username'] : $EE_signup->session->userdata['screen_name'],
                'ip_address'  => $EE_signup->input->ip_address(),
                'date'      => $EE_signup->localize->now,
                'anon'      => 'y',
                'site_id'   => $EE_signup->config->item('site_id')
            );


            $query_12 = "SELECT name FROM exp_online_users WHERE  member_id = '" . $data['member_id'] . "'";
            $query_session = $EE_signup->db->query($query_12);

            if($query_session->num_rows != 0) {
                $EE_signup->db->query($EE_signup->db->update_string('exp_online_users', $data, array("ip_address" => $EE_signup->input->ip_address(), "member_id" => $data['member_id'])));
            } else {
                $EE_signup->db->query($EE_signup->db->insert_string('exp_online_users', $data));
            }
            // login session sets ends

            echo '1'; //signup scuccess
        } else {
            //echo '-3';
            //exit(0);
        }
    }


    /**********LOGIN FUNCTION************/
    public function login($newuserdata) {
        //error_log('in login fucntion here___________________1________________________');
        $EE_login =& get_instance(); //Access super Object using this instance within function
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($newuserdata); echo '</pre>';
        $username = $newuserdata['email'];
        $password = $newuserdata['password'];

        //global $FNS, $IN, $LOC, $TMPL, $DB, $SESS, $PREFS; //deprecated

        $password = $EE_login->functions->hash(stripslashes($password));

        $sql = "SELECT exp_members.password, exp_members.unique_id, exp_members.member_id, exp_members.group_id, exp_members.screen_name
    FROM   exp_members
    WHERE  username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";

        //error_log("in login function ".$sql);

        $query = $EE_login->db->query($sql);
        //error_log('here______________________2_____________________  Member_id: '.$query->row('member_id').'-----NUm Rows: '.$query->num_rows());
        if ($query->num_rows() != 0) {


            ////error_log('here______________________3_____________________');
            /****************************** start session set code ***********************************/
            $EE_login->session->gc_probability = 100;
            $EE_login->session->delete_old_sessions();

            /** ----------------------------------------
            /**  Set cookie expiration
            /** ----------------------------------------*/
            // login session sets start


            // set default expiration to one day
            if ($EE_login->TMPL->fetch_param('expire')) {
                $expire = $EE_login->TMPL->fetch_param('expire');
            }
            /** ----------------------------------------
            /**  Log user in
            /** ----------------------------------------*/
            $expire = 60*60*24*1;

            $EE_login->functions->set_cookie($EE_login->session->c_expire , time()+$expire, $expire);
            $EE_login->functions->set_cookie($EE_login->session->c_uniqueid , $query->row('unique_id'), $expire);
            $EE_login->functions->set_cookie($EE_login->session->c_password , $query->row('password'),  $expire);
            $EE_login->functions->set_cookie($EE_login->session->c_anon , 1,  $expire);

            /** ----------------------------------------
            /**  Create a new session
            /** ----------------------------------------*/
            $EE_login->session->create_new_session($query->row('member_id'));

            /** ----------------------------------------
            /**  Update existing session variables
            /** ----------------------------------------*/

            $EE_login->session->userdata['screen_name']  = $query->row('screen_name');
            $EE_login->session->userdata['username']    = $query->row('username');
            $EE_login->session->userdata['member_id']   = $query->row('member_id');
            $EE_login->session->userdata['group_id']    = $query->row('group_id');


            /** ----------------------------------------
            /**  Update stats
            /** ----------------------------------------*/

            $ip_address = $newuserdata['ip_address'];
            $data = array(
                'member_id'   => $EE_login->session->userdata['member_id'],
                'name'      => ($EE_login->session->userdata['screen_name'] == '') ? $EE_login->session->userdata['username'] : $EE_login->session->userdata['screen_name'],
                'ip_address'  => $ip_address,
                'date'      => $EE_login->localize->now,
                'anon'      => 'y',
                'site_id'   => $EE_login->config->item('site_id')
            );

            //error_log("Member ID: ".$data['member_id']."-------Screen Name--------".$data['name']."-------Location-------".$data['ip_address']);

            $query_12 = "SELECT name FROM exp_online_users WHERE  member_id = '" . $query->row('member_id') . "'";

            $query_session = $EE_login->db->query($query_12);

            if($query_session->num_rows() != 0) {

                $EE_login->db->query($EE_login->db->update_string('exp_online_users', $data, array("ip_address" => $ip_address, "member_id" => $query->row('member_id'))));

            } else {
                $EE_login->db->query($EE_login->db->insert_string('exp_online_users', $data));
            }

            //error_log('here_________________________in login__________________');
            // login session sets ends
            //header("Location: ' . STATIC_URL . 'ee/index.php/register/post-login-normal/");
            //exit(0);
            echo '1';
        } else {
            //not valid username or password
            //do what ever you want to do
            echo 'not_valid';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: It is not a coincidence that your code is long and also that you have been stuck on it for a long time. If you try and reduce your code down into the smallest possible example which triggers the problem, you will probably find the cause of the problem. Try commenting out parts of your code until you find which bit causes the error, then update your question with only that concise example.

Comment: @AdrianMacneil:alright!!!!i will try tht..thx.But in the error its given that line 2929 causes error..My code is not that big,so which line should i thing it is?just asking

Comment: Could you please indicate your EE Version?

Comment: @MaxLazar:2.4 it is....is it because of that?

Comment: similar kind of error

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/186136/#879823

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EE 2.4, in *libraries/Template.php* on line 2929 we have

```
if (isset($this->EE->session->userdata[$val]) AND ($val == 'group_description' OR strval($this->EE->session->userdata[$val]) != ''))
```

line 226 in your code, try to add "0,":

```
        $EE_login->session->userdata['screen_name']  = $query->row(0,'screen_name');
        $EE_login->session->userdata['username']    = $query->row(0,'username');
        $EE_login->session->userdata['member_id']   = $query->row(0, 'member_id');
        $EE_login->session->userdata['group_id']    = $query->row(0,'group_id');
```

Comment: ok....trying...thx for the time though!!!

Comment: it is possible, that when you do  $query = $EE_login->db->query($sql); (line 187) is return more then 1 result...

Comment: wohoooooo...its done...Man how did you find it...its working..

Comment: well its working ,but how did you find the error...i mean why was that not working...?

Comment: I just start from the line where this error happens (in template library), indicated possible variables and check where your modify this variables in your code. I think that it is happen because your query on line 187 is return more then one result. In this case ->row is return not string but object which is can't be processed by strval   (this function cannot use for objects that do not implement the __toString() method)

Comment: where can i find this template library?

Comment: /system_dir/expressionengine/libraries/Template.php